# Failed to instantiate component or class

Tags: yii2

I have moved my Yii application to a production environment.

It is built using 2amigos Template with ConfigKit and Usuario and in the development environment it works perfectly, but as soon as I went live I got an error:

```
ReflectionException: Class Da\User\Bootstrap does not exist in /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:508

Stack trace:

#0 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(508): ReflectionClass->__construct('Da\\User\\Bootstr...')
#1 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(386): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('Da\\User\\Bootstr...')
#2 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(171): yii\di\Container->build('Da\\User\\Bootstr...', Array, Array)
#3 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#9 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/bootstrap/web.php(18): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#10 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/public/index.php(46): require('/homepages/21/d...')
#11 {main}

Next yii\di\NotInstantiableException: Failed to instantiate component or class "Da\User\Bootstrap". in /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:510

Stack trace:

#0 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(386): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('Da\\User\\Bootstr...')
#1 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(171): yii\di\Container->build('Da\\User\\Bootstr...', Array, Array)
#2 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(345): yii\di\Container->get('Da\\User\\Bootstr...', Array)
#3 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
#8 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/bootstrap/web.php(18): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#9 /homepages/21/d800176243/htdocs/twopointsix/public/index.php(46): require('/homepages/21/d...')
#10 {main}
```

What may be causing this or where should I look for the error?

First configuration file:

```
use SideKit\Config\ConfigKit;

return [

     *
     * Base class for all application classes. Here we configure the attributes
     * that do not hold any object configuration such as "components" or
     * "modules". The configuration of those properties are within submodules of the same name.
     */

    'id' => 'Two Point Six',

    'name' => 'Two Point Six',

    'basePath' => ConfigKit::config()->getBasePath(),

    'vendorPath' => ConfigKit::config()->getVendorPath(),

    'runtimePath' => ConfigKit::config()->getRuntimePath(),

    'language' => ConfigKit::env()->get('APP_LANGUAGE'),

    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
];
```

User module code:

```
 <?php

    return [

         * Dos Amigos User Module
 '''''

        'class' => 'Da\User\Module',
        'enableRegistration' => true,
        'administratorPermissionName' => 'administrator',
        'enableGdprCompliance' => true,
        'mailParams' => ['fromEmail' => 'no-reply@twopointsix.com'],

        'classMap' => [
           ~~~~~~~~~
        ],

        'controllerMap' => [
            ~~~~~~~~
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Do your dev & prod vendor folders match? Look like you've downloaded a package and not included it with live.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, I copied everything again just in case.

Comment: Can you show your web.php config?

Comment: I have added the code, it doesnt have a Web.php with the ConfigKit and i think thats where im struggling to pick it up.

Comment: Did you use composer update to install this plugin? If yes, open your composer.json and check if plugin is included.

Comment: yeah. it is included

Comment: The first configuration file seems to be missing the starting comment character sequence, `/*`.

Comment: What is the meaning of the unindented `'''''` in the last part?